# npm login not allowing login to github

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I try to run the following in the terminal it should ask me for username and password but nothing comes up other than the error bellow.

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@Psychedelic

npm notice Log in on https://npm.pkg.github.com/
npm ERR! code ENYI
npm ERR! Web login not supported`
```

Any ideas?

I think i might need to create a ~/.npmrc file with token etc but can't work out how to do that.

Comment: Did you [follow the GitHub instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry)? It talks about the required `.npmrc` steps.

Answer (score 38):

If you use npm version 9, you should add the argument `--auth-type=legacy` with `npm adduser` or `npm login`. Otherwise, you will get error `npm ERR! Web login not supported`.

Answer (score 16):

Since npm v9, `--auth-type=legacy` argument is required to authenticate with GitHub Packages.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-login

Answer (score 7):

NPM V9 is now using web login as its default authentication type. As NPM supports the publication of private packages to their registry it also supports using a **Private Registry**. Here you are using a private registry like **Verdaccio** I assume. With the release of NPM V9 there are major breaking changes. To know more about them [Check this blog](https://betterprogramming.pub/exploring-new-features-in-npm-9-bea4631a96d6).

One Of those impacted changes are `auth-type` which were used for the npm `login` and `adduser` **CLI** Commands.

- Now the `auth-type` is web login by `default`.
- There are only two types of of `auth-type` supported  `web` and `legacy`.

So the easy solution to generate a `.npmrc` token in your system is to force the `auth-type` all the time like this:

> npm login --registry=https://registry.dojo.com --auth-type=legacy

If it still doesn't work try increasing the log level with

> npm login --registry=https://registry.dojo.com --auth-type=legacy --loglevel=verbose

Comment: Just additional note, here are the docs for your answer https://verdaccio.org/docs/setup-npm#npm-login-with-npm9-or-higher

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and this worked for me:

Add `.npmrc` file to your project in the same directory as your `package.json` file with this content:

```
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=TOKEN
```

Replace `OWNER` with the name of the user or organization account on GitHub that owns the repository containing your project, And `TOKEN` with your personal access token (classic).

I did the steps above instead of `npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`.
Followed by a `npm run build` at the end.

Read the documentation on [Working with the npm registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry) for more.

Comment: Just tried this and am still getting the same error

Comment: No need to do `npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` anymore. Just proceed with `npm run build` followed by `npm start`, will do the job. Also, make sure your GitHub is connected/logged in to your VSCode.

Comment: Also the other answer _https://stackoverflow.com/a/74519453/16177977_ works better. Go for it. Use `npm login --scope=@OWNER --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --auth-type=legacy`.